Inconsistency problem in Cauchy-Schwartz inequality with different inner products.
I can not work around an inconsistency I found when applyting Cauchy-Schwartz using two different inner products. The problem is the following:

Let $v,u$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\langle\cdot\rangle$ be the canonical inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $\langle a,b\rangle=a^Tb$, and $\langle\cdot\rangle_G$ be the inner product defined by the positive definite matrix $G$, i.e. $\langle a,b \rangle_G=a^TGb$. Let $u_G=G^{-1}u$ ($G^{-1}$ always exists since $G$ is positive definite). We have the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle v,u \rangle &= v^Tu \\
\langle v,u_G \rangle_G = v^TGu_G&=v^T GG^{-1}u=v^Tu=\langle v,u\rangle\\
\end{align}
$$
If we define $\|a\|=\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}$ and $\|a\|_G=\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle_G}$  and $f(v)=\langle v,u \rangle$ and $f_G(v)=\langle v,u_G\rangle_G$ (we have $f(v)=f_G(v)$), from the Cauchy Schwartz inequality we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(v)&=\langle v,u\rangle \leq\|v\|\|u\| \text{ with equality if } v=\lambda u, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}  \\
f(v)&=
f_G(v)=\langle v,u_G\rangle_G \leq\|v\|_G\|u_G\|_G \text{ with equality if } v=\lambda_G u_G, \lambda_G\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0} 
\end{align}
$$
So, the following problem
$$
\max_{v,\|v\|=1}f(v)
$$
will have a unique solution at $v=\frac{u}{\|u\|}$ and
$$
\max_{v,\|v\|=1}f_G(v)
$$
will have a unique solution at $v=\frac{u_G}{\|u_G\|}$. Since we established that $f(v)=f_G(v)$ we have that $\frac{u}{\|u\|}=\frac{u_G}{\|u_G\|}$, or, put differently $u_G=G^{-1}u=\gamma u$ for a scalar $\gamma$. However this is not true for any $u$ which is not an eigenvector of $G^{-1}$. Where is the problem?

For context, I came around this problem when I learned that the gradient of a function is metric dependent to allow the directional derivative to be metric independent.

The problem is that the first maximum is taken among the $v$ with $\|v\| = 1,$ whereas the second maximum should be taken among the $v$ with $\|v\|_G = 1.$ You were being very careful to distinguish between the two norms right until that point.

Hey, thanks for the answer, I think it's right. I actually had this problem since in optimization theory we define the gradient as the direction of maximal increase of the function as a given point, so I could not understand that this direction depends on the metric. However, I see that it is the direction of maximal increase per unit length, where the length is actually measured by the metric. So it makes sense that this direction actually depends on the metric.
